# Drag and drop items in grid view with gap

Tags: java, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio, gridview

I have seen many library, making drag and drop GridView, but every library is making a gapless item, one to another.

I want to make android application which can increment button/items, move/resize/dispose, or simply i want to make android application to make customizable remote control, and save the layout.

The layout can be Grid Layout, but not 'sticks' one item to another, or the items can be 'floating' and can be moved without overlapping each other.

Is there any libraries or guides/tutorial that relevant to my case?

I have been googling for about 3 hours and got nothing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Some quick googling led me to the below explanation found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html).

> **Space**
>
> Space between children may be specified either by using instances of
>   the dedicated Space view or by setting the leftMargin, topMargin,
>   rightMargin and bottomMargin layout parameters. When the
>   useDefaultMargins property is set, default margins around children are
>   automatically allocated based on the prevailing UI style guide for the
>   platform. Each of the margins so defined may be independently
>   overridden by an assignment to the appropriate layout parameter.
>   Default values will generally produce a reasonable spacing between
>   components but values may change between different releases of the
>   platform.